# Solutions for frontpage that consist of only blocks

Tags: 7, blocks

What methods are there to construct a frontpage that consist of only blocks. I know i can setup panels + pagemanager and add blocks in that manner, but it seems a bit overkill to install panels just for 1 page of the site. Another solution was to create an empty Views page, but that seems a bit hacky.

Having that the frontpage consist of only blocks, what other methods are there that doesnt seem hacky or bloated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you could use a lightweight module such as [Empty Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_page):

> The Empty Page module is a simple empty page solution. It provides an
>   interface that assists in managing "empty" menu callbacks, mostly used
>   for pages that only consist of blocks.

Then you can create and place blocks wherever you want, and restrict them to the front page if desired.

If you need to customize the general layout, you can use something like [Themekey:](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

And use a sub-theme of your main theme for just the front page - then you can alter it to suit the layout of just containing blocks in whatever format you want and whatever regions you need.

Answer (score 0):

The pages are already built from blocks, where the 'main content' block is the page content. These blocks are positioned in regions defined in the template.

I guess you want to reorganize the blocks? Have maybe multiple columns and so? Then you can either use panels or alter the theme with the regions you want. (This basically is what panels does, but at the position of the 'main content block'. Leaving the other blocks intact.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was the minimal setup by using: https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page